# Not able to accept response from $.ajax api Post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to call a rest api from my login page on click of a button. I am using $.ajax to do so. The POST request gets sent and 200 code is also showing on backend. But in my browser network tab it shows failed. I don't know what is wrong. I am trying to print the response in the console when response comes from api, but nothing get printed. That means api is getting the POST req, it is generating a token for me and sending it to me but my client side is failing to get the response. Here is my code and essential screenshots. P.S. I don't get any error in console.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from "react-router"
require("./login.css")
import valueLink from 'valuelink'
import $ from 'jquery'

    export default class LogInComponent extends Component {
        handleLoginButtonClick() {
            var settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://******appspot.com/auth/login/",
                "method": "POST",
                "credentials": 'include',
                "headers": {
                    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
                "data": {
                    "password": "****",
                    "username": "****"
                }
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function () {
                alert("success");
            });
        }



        render(){
            return (
                <div className="LoginPage">
                    <div className="login-page">
                        <div className="form">
                            <form className="login-form">
                                <input id="username" type="username" placeholder="username"/>
                                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                                <button onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick}>login</button>
                                <p className="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Request Username and Password</a></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

This is my network tab

[image]

This is when I click :3000... from initiator column. The highlighted line is where it takes me.

[image]

Comment: submit buttons submit, you do not cancel the click action.

Comment: Yeah. Coz I want to trigger the api on that login button click.

Comment: So you do it on the ajax call, you need to cancel the click action...

Comment: @epascarello thanks man for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button submits the form when clicked because the default type for the button element is `submit`. This happens even when you give it your own click handler. The form submit basically just reloads your page since the form lacks the `action`-attribute, so it reloads during your ajax request, which cancels it (as you can see from your network tab). You have several ways to solve this.

You can add `type="button"` to the button element:

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick}>login</button>
```

You can cancel the default native event handling in the onClick handler:

```
handleLoginButtonClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

You can use an onSubmit handler on the form element, instead of an onClick handler on the button:

```
<form className="login-form" onSubmit={this.handleLoginFormSubmit}>
    ...
</form>
```

with

```
handleLoginFormSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting
    ...
}
```